# LookupError: App 'app' doesn't have a 'CustomUser' model

Tags: python, django

So I added the following line in my `settings.py`:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app.CustomUser'
```

And I got the error:

```
LookupError: App 'app' doesn't have a 'CustomUser' model.
```

The last line in error is:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'app.CustomUser' that has not been installed
```

Here is my CustomerUser class in `app/models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.utils import timezone

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='CustomUser')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

I get this error while trying to run makemigrations. I already have an existing db, and I'm redoing my models. I tried deleting the database file, and no luck.

Comment: Why do you add a O2O field to User model?

Comment: Also your `CustomUser` is abstract, it does not create tables itself and therefore you cannot replace `User` with it

Comment: Read docs for more details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Comment: @awesoon I want there to be only one user by each username

Comment: This is implemented by adding an unique index (`unique=True`) to username which is already done in `AbstractUser`

Comment: If you need to migrate an existing database (from django's `User` to your `CustomUser`) you need to have a clear understanding how models are reflecting to the DB schema and what actual SQL will be generated by migrations (you can start with [`sqlmigrate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-sqlmigrate)). If you can drop DB you just need to follow official documentation. You don't need a one2one to User, because it does not make sense if your intent is to replace built-in `User` model with `CustomUser`